# Windows 7 and Ubuntu Boot/Corruption Problems

Tags: installation, boot, dual-boot, windows, windows-7

I searched around, but I couldn't find the answer to why Windows 7 Ultimate 64x and Ubuntu 12.04 LTS 64x couldn't live together happily on my Asus G1s-X1 laptop.

I had Windows 7 Ultimate 64x installed on the laptop when I bought it (bought it used, it comes with Vista new) and I wanted to try out Ubuntu and see what all the hype about the free OS was. I installed Ubuntu on an external 80GB iomega HDD with Windows 7 on my main drive.

They both work fine for about 2-3 weeks, until Ubuntu suddenly is unable to boot. A few days after Ubuntu fails, Windows corrupts majorly (`winload.exe`, `ntkrnlpa.exe`, and various others corrupt randomly) and Windows Recovery Environment is completely useless.

Booting to a live USB with Ubuntu and trying to reinstall it fails, and trying to wipe the main drive and install it there fails as well (something about my graphics card.) I managed to get Windows 7 Ultimate 64x back up and running (after many disk formats) but now I am left with a broken (and invisible) Ubuntu installation on the external drive.

Is there any way to get the broken and non-bootable Ubuntu installation off the HDD without damaging or erasing the  many files and programs installed and stored on the 80GB drive?

Answer (score 1):

I have a drive on which Ubuntu cannot see anything but Windows 7 sees the NTFS partitions and two healthy ext4 partitions that Windows cannot access. Curiously, gparted claims that the drive has no valid partition table but Arcronis True Image (non-free) can see all partitions on that drive. I have recovered my data, but I am still struggling to find a way to restore the disk to a correct state without erasing everything and restoring it from the Acronis backup.

If you can see all your partitions in Windows 7 Control Panel ->System and Security -> Administrative Tools -> Computer Management -> Storage -> Disk Management, then Acronis True Image is likely able to extract all the date. Acronis offers a free trial, so you can know if it is useful for you before paying.